# How to get basic calls, messages and data usage statistics in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I need to get some basic phone usage stats in my app:

- total duration of outgoing calls in last month
- total number of sms messages sent in last month
- total mobile data usage in last month

How can I do that in iOS (Swift or Objective-C)? Is it even possible?

Comment: Have you tried something already, or at least Googled for it?

Comment: The only solutions that I've found are for jailbroken phones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. The apps run in a sandboxed environment and that data is not available to your app.

Comment: Yeah, it isn't possible and I can't seeing Apple changing that. I could see it as an invasion of privacy for unnecessary data.